# Select Data After Specific Date

Tags: r, date

I would like to be able to select dates from a data frame after or before a specific date.  For example using quandl data on Gold prices.

```
pGold <- read.csv('http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/BUNDESBANK/BBK01_WT5511.csv?&trim_start=1968-04-01&trim_end=2014-01-08&sort_order=desc', colClasses=c('Date'='Date'))

pGold$asDate <- as.Date(pGold$Date)

head(pGold)
        Date   Value
1 2014-01-08 1226.50
2 2014-01-07 1237.50
3 2014-01-06 1238.00
4 2014-01-03 1232.25
5 2014-01-02 1219.75
6 2013-12-31 1201.50

plot(pGold[pGold$Date>"2012-01-01",], type="l", main="Price of Gold (USD)"))
```

[image]

Comment: And your problem is? Your code works if you leave out the second line.  You don't need to create the `asDate` variable because `Date` is already a `Date` column. If you plot `pGold` without that then `pGold` is a 2-column data frame and you get the chart you show. What's your problem? Apart from the extra `)` on the plot function??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've practically done it.

```
pGold <- read.csv('http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/BUNDESBANK/BBK01_WT5511.csv?&trim_start=1968-04-01&trim_end=2014-01-08&sort_order=desc', colClasses=c('Date'='Date'))
plot(subset(pGold,Date>"2012-01-01"),type="l")
```

gets you:

[image]

or if you want `ggplot` niceness:

```
ggplot(subset(pGold,Date>"2012-01-01"), aes(x=Date,y=Value))+geom_line()
```

gets you:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest for time series stuff, use `xts` package. It provides very easy subsetting features as demonstrated below.

```
require(xts)

Gold <- xts(pGold[, 2], pGold[, 1])

Gold["2014"]
##               [,1]
## 2014-01-02 1219.75
## 2014-01-03 1232.25
## 2014-01-06 1238.00
## 2014-01-07 1237.50
## 2014-01-08 1226.50

plot(Gold['201310/201312'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can compare dates

```
data <- as.Date("2013-10-1")
data1 <- as.Date("2013-08-22")
data1 > data
## [1] FALSE
data1 < data
## [1] TRUE
data
## [1] "2013-10-01"
data1
## [1] "2013-08-22"
```

Comment: Awesome, thought it was something simple! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.  But it is a little clunky.

Convert date to String.

```
pGold$Sdate <- do.call(rbind, lapply(pGold$Date,toString))
```

Turn into columns labelled year, month, and day.

```
pGold[c("Year", "Month", "Day")] <- 
    do.call(rbind, lapply((strsplit(pGold$Sdate, split="\\-")),as.numeric))
```

Plot Data.

```
with(pGold[pGold$Year>=2012,], 
    plot(Date,Value, type="l", main="Price of Gold (USD)"))
```

Comment: You might want to look at the `lubridate` package, where getting the month, year, and day from a Date object is as easy as `month(d)`, `year(d)` and `day(d)`. You'll never parse a date string again!