# Plot specific date range with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot data within a specific date range for individuals. I've pasted example code below that has worked before, but I don't wall all the data, just what happens after 11/30/2016. I've tried the solution shown here ([Select Data After Specific Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554166/select-data-after-specific-date)), but I get "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only." Any ideas?

```
 mydf<- data.frame(Date = as.Date(Subject$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                   variable1 = (Subject$var1),
                   variable2 = (Subject$var2), 
                   variable3 = (Subject$var3),
                   variable4 = (Subject$var4))

ggplot(mydf, aes(Date > "2016-11-30", variable1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(color = "blue", fill = "lightskyblue") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
  ylab("") + xlab("")+ 
  ggtitle("Variable 1 units") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", 
               date_labels = "%b%y") + 
  theme_hc()
```

Comment: You need to subset the data, something like `ggplot(mydf[mydf$Date>"2016-11-30", ], aes(Date, variable1))`. `Date>"2016-11-30"` by itself generates a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values.

Comment: Subset your data first then feed into ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try subsetting the dataframe while feeding it to `ggplot` like this:

```
ggplot(data=mydf[which(mydf$Date>"2016-11-30"),],
       aes(x=Date, y=variable1)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       stat_smooth(color = "blue", fill = "lightskyblue") +
       theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
       ylab("") + xlab("")+ 
       ggtitle("Variable 1 units") + 
       scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", 
                    date_labels = "%b%y") + 
       theme_hc()
```

Comment: "2016-11-30" is a character string. Shouldn't it be something like `as.Date("2016-11-30", format = "%Y-%m-%d")`?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point to mention, but in this case it will work the same way with or without 'as.Date'. We can test this by running variations of: "2016-11-30" > "2016-11-29" and seeing if it prints true/false in the R console. The case illustrated here prints true.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It may be simpler and more duplicable to create a second subset dataframe. Converting class(mydf$Date) to POSIXct and assuming the "format="%Y-%m-%d" as earlier commenters mentioned:

```
mydf$Date <- as.POSIXct(mydf$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
after1130 <- subset(mydf, Date > "2016-11-30")
ggplot(data=after1130, +
   aes(x=Date, y=variable1)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(color = "blue", fill = "lightskyblue") +
   theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
   ylab("") + xlab("")+ 
   ggtitle("Variable 1 units") + 
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "months", 
                date_labels = "%b%y") + 
   theme_hc()
```

This method allows you to easily call the subset in the future for statistics and/or more plotting.